# Show convergence of complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to show that the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n}
$$
converges.

My first idea was to use ratio test but that does not help since
$$
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1
$$

Comment: A test that uses absolute values will not work on this, as the series isn't absolutely convergent.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/996553/42969

Comment: Break the series as $\sum (-1)^ka_k+i\sum (-1)^kb_k$ where $a_k,b_k$ are positive reals decreasing to $0,$ so they converge by the alternating series rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining precisely where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118686/determining-precisely-where-sum-n-1-infty-fracznn-converges)

Comment: (Yes, it did.) This also answers your question: [Is $\sum{\frac{i^{n}}{n}}$ convergent or divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438217/is-sum-fracinn-convergent-or-divergent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the below series:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n}=-\ln \left(1-x\right)$$

$$x=i\Rightarrow \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{i^n}{n}=-\ln \left(1-i\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(2\right)+\frac{i\pi }{4}$$
Finally:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{i^n}{n}=-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(2\right)+\frac{\pi }{4}i$$
note:
$$\ln \left(a+bi\right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(a^2+b^2\right)+i\arctan \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Comment: This answer is correct but "cheating": the first line suffices to answer much more than what was asked, but the knowledge it implicitly assumes does not correspond to the question's level (I wonder if the accepter fully understood it). Anyway, that question was a (multi-)duplicate.